# Using Video with QR code

Tags: youtube, video, url

I want to set up a digital nature trail with a video of information at each post. The QR code on the post will reference the video. The QR code (URL) must be permanent but the video will change with the seasons. Can I do this using YouTube for the video and URL? If not can you suggest an alternative access solution? We are a small voluntary organisation so free is best!

Comment: Try to find a free URL redirection service that lets you change the target URL. You'll obviously need to register, but I think such services do exist. Or, similar to @rub%c3%a9n's suggestion, point the URL to a server you control and have it redirect to the appropriate video.

Answer (score 1):

On Youtube each video has its own URL so it's not possible to use the same URL for different videos but you could embed a video on a web page and change the embedded video, so the web page URL will not change, only its content.

For general instructions on how to embed a video on a web page, see [Embed videos & playlists](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=en). If you want to ask for a software recommendation consider to post a question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have embedded the video in our website but can't get it to use full screen thus making it small on a smartphone. I used BT Community Kit to build the site. I have also tried embedding the link into my Google Maps trail and then embedding the map in the website - that works but some people with iphones have trouble accessing the My Maps google link.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered including a link to a Playlist, instead of a specific video?  Like the other answer mentioned, you can't really change an existing video, but you can add/remove items with a playlist without the playlist URL changing.